# Signature not matching the sig obtained from MyEtherWallet

Tags: myetherwallet, signature, ecrecover

I am serializing the unsigned txn in C, then I found Keccak-256 hash and I signed it with the privatekey. However, the resulting signature is not the same as in MyEtherWallet for the same values(sender,to, value..)

```
void main()
{
    uint8_t digest[32];
    uint8_t sig[64], sig2[64], priv[32], *pby, unsigned_txn[200]={0};
    const ecdsa_curve *curve = &secp256k1;

    uint8_t txLen_,txLen, nonce_, gasPriceLen_,gasPrice_[33],gasLimLen_, gasLim_[33],toLen_, to_[21], valLen_,value_[33], data_, chainId_;

    //hardcoding the txn components for now
    memcpy(&txLen,"\x2b",1);     //actual length of the txn (for printing here)
    memcpy(&txLen_,"\xeb",1);      //length specified in unsigned txn
    memcpy(&nonce_,"\x02",1);
    memcpy(&gasPriceLen_, "\x84",1);
    memcpy(&gasPrice_, "\x3b\x9a\xca\x00", 4);
    memcpy(&gasLimLen_, "\x82",1);
    memcpy(&gasLim_, "\x52\x08", 2);
    memcpy(&toLen_, "\x94", 1);
    memcpy(&to_, "\x8f\x87\xd7\x0d\xb7\x15\xae\x66\xba\xd9\x8e\x6f\x36\xa0\x6e\x45\x39\x45\x0a\x3c", 20);
    memcpy(&valLen_, "\x88",1);
    memcpy(&value_, "\xb1\xa2\xbc\x2e\xc5\x00\x00", 8);
    memcpy(&data_, "\x80",1);
    memcpy(&chainId_,"\x04",1);
    struct unsignedTxn tx={txLen_, nonce_,gasPriceLen_, gasPrice_,gasLimLen_, gasLim_,toLen_, to_,valLen_, value_, data_, chainId_};


    //RLP encoding of the unsigned txn

    memcpy(&unsigned_txn, &txLen_, 1);  
    memcpy(&unsigned_txn[1], &nonce_, 1);
    memcpy(&unsigned_txn[2], &gasPriceLen_, 1); 
    memcpy(&unsigned_txn[3], &gasPrice_, (int)(gasPriceLen_)-128);
    memcpy(&unsigned_txn[3+(int)gasPriceLen_-128], &gasLimLen_, 1);
    memcpy(&unsigned_txn[4+(int)gasPriceLen_-128], &gasLim_,(int)gasLimLen_-128);
    memcpy(&unsigned_txn[4+(int)gasPriceLen_-128 + (int)gasLimLen_-128], &toLen_, 1);
    memcpy(&unsigned_txn[5+(int)gasPriceLen_-128 + (int)gasLimLen_-128],&to_, (int)toLen_-128);
    memcpy(&unsigned_txn[5+(int)gasPriceLen_-128 + (int)gasLimLen_-128+(int)toLen_-128], &valLen_, 1);
    memcpy(&unsigned_txn[6+(int)gasPriceLen_-128 + (int)gasLimLen_-128+(int)toLen_-128], &value_, (int)valLen_-128);
    memcpy(&unsigned_txn[6+(int)gasPriceLen_-128 + (int)gasLimLen_-128+(int)toLen_-128+(int)valLen_-128], &data_, 1);
    memcpy(&unsigned_txn[7+(int)gasPriceLen_-128 + (int)gasLimLen_-128+(int)toLen_-128+(int)valLen_-128], "\x04\x80\x80", 3);



    uint8_t message[200];
    memcpy(&message, "\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n", 25);
    memcpy(&message[25], &unsigned_txn, (int)txLen+1);

    printf("\nSerialized Unsigned Transaction\n");

    for(int i=0; i<25+(int)txLen+1; i++) 
    {
        printf("%02x", message[i]);
    }

    keccak_256(message, 25+(int)txLen+1, digest);

    printf("\nUnsigned Transaction Digest\n");

    for(int i=0; i<32; i++) 
    {
        printf("%02x", digest[i]);
    }

    ecdsa_sign_digest(curve,priv,digest,sig,&pby,NULL);

    printf("\nSignature (64 bytes)\n");

    for(int i=0; i<64; i++) 
    {
        printf("%02x",sig[i]);
    }
}
```

Here is my output:

```
Serialized Unsigned Transaction
9e7468657265756d205369676e6564204d6573736167653a0aeb02843b9aca00825208948f87d70db715ae66bad98e6f36a06e4539450a3c88b1a2bc2ec500000080048080

Unsigned Transaction Digest
df7419e94bfa4901441c60ca7155e7a6da2a9e73674605a0df3ff71b3ba31f18

Signature (64 bytes)
bbf9e67ad1b0dafdcab382b6efafe6e792c120dbffcf9d10cabeb6dd7c515fc866db3ae2635fc14a4d6204e46e22e4c0825a2acceded4943187e96d902a5a1e2
```

Here is the signed transaction on MyEtherWallet:
[image]

Comment: It might be helpful to make use of a library such as this: https://github.com/firefly/wallet/tree/master/source/libs/ethers/src - unfortunately I am unfamiliar with C.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that transactions are not signed with the "\x19Ethereum.." prefix. Also EC signatures have a random component so it doesn't make sense to compare possible different implementations.