# Insufficient funds for gas * price + value web3 sendSignedTransaction

Tags: web3js, ether, sendtransaction

My wallet balance is 3.994937 RIN and I have set value (to be sent) to 0.00005 RIN (50000000000000 Wei) and I have set both gasPrice to 5208 (21000)and gas Limit to 5208 (21000 Wei).

ChainId=4

However, I am getting the following error (as in the console):

insufficient funds for gas * price + value

Signed transaction I am trying to broadcast:

0xf86780**825208825208**948f87d70db715ae66bad98e6f36a06e4539450a3c**862d79883d2000**802ba057d0655b6cd90831248058c9bc9a92f10db321ee6f97fca3359f2c0f33e07005a06dd7c20022c11698a9be524845d8caac9944c833db27242470f15ccf9d4e5986

[image]

Comment: The error refers to the amount of ether in your wallet, not the amount of RIN (or any other token for that matter) in your wallet. This error tells you that you do not have a sufficient amount of ether required in order to complete the transaction.

Comment: Other than that (i.e., after you resolve this problem by loading some ether into your wallet), a gas-limit of 21000 is sufficient only for one type of transaction, and that it the transaction of sending ether from your wallet to some other wallet. Any other type of transaction (for example, transferring RIN tokens from your wallet to some other wallet) will necessarily require more than 21000 gas units. So you will have to increase that value, and subsequently (in order to avoid running into your original error once again), load more ether into your wallet (since the gas-limit has increased).

Comment: Other than that (i.e., after you resolve this problem by setting a higher gas-limit), a gas-price of 21000 is extremely low, and pretty much guarantees that your transaction will not be executed in this lifetime or in the next. It should be at least 9-digit long if you wanna get it done within a reasonable time-frame.

Comment: The error was insufficient funds for gas*price+value, not insufficient funds for gas for the transaction i.e. it is implying that the balance is low. Also, I am broadcasting the txn on Rinkeby testnet (chainId = 4), not on the Ethereum mainnet. So I think Rinkeby tokens will be expended.

Comment: @RiyaSingh What is your Ether balance on Rinkeby for the Ethereum account you are using? Also, where is that error coming from ("insufficient funds for gas * price + value"), is the error being generated by Javascript or is it coming from the contract?

Comment: @Jay Balance is 3.994865996 RIN. And the error is generated by javascript.

Comment: @RiyaSingh What is RIN? I am asking about your Ether balance. Please share the public key you are using so I can check. :)

Comment: Also just keep in mind that since the error message is being generated by Javascript, chances are that any part of the Ethereum function call which fails would result in the same error (i.e. the error message might not accurately represent the actual error).

Comment: It makes sense that the actual error might be different. I am actually unsure about the serialization format of the txn I am trying to broadcast. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/78770/signature-not-matching-the-sig-obtained-from-myetherwallet Can you please help out with this issue?

Comment: How did you sign the transaction? Sometime that error appears when the transaction was signed incorrectly.

Comment: Unlike some errors, the "Insufficient funds" error is actually quite solid in the fact that it represents the exact error (I don't recall getting it for anything other than the case of `web3.eth.getBalance(account) < gas * gasPrice + value`). The RIN balance of your wallet is not relevant here, and neither does the amount of RIN that you pass as input to the function (unless you're mistakenly passing it in the `value` field). The error is about the lack of **ether** in your wallet... but hey, I've explained that already and you ignored, so not much more can be done at this point...